# ASP.NET MVC 3 Custom MembershipProvider and MembershipUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, membership-provider

I do my little project on ASP.NET MVC 3 with EF Model and custom user tables (mostly for education). I read the tutorial and I know that I must inherit from MembershipProvider to make my custom one. I do not have any roles in this project. I just want to make simple authentication by email and password (custom password hashing and etc.) with no extra features. In default MembershipProvider all authorization does by username. But in my project it does by email, username is using for other purposes. Questions:

1. How to swap email and username?
2. If I will use [Authorize] attribute, must I use RoleProvider and is there any required members in MembershipProvider class to implement for using that attribute?
3. Maybe do not inherit and do not use MembershipProvider at all? Just use my own Repository class for authorization and authentication?

Answer (score 2):

1. just put their email address in the username field.
2. No, you don't need RoleProvider.
3. You can implement any authentication you want, but you should stick with Membership unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: I knew that someone would offer me to put email in username field. But I don't like to do such thing. What are reasons to stick Membership other than using default controls like Login?

Comment: @SPYke - OK, let me get this straight, you want to use their email as their username, but you don't want to treat their email as their username?  That doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Email as login, username I will show as name or nickname on site.

Comment: per your question, Mystere Man is right -- just use the email address where you would use the username. As far as "username I will show as name or nickname", do you mean something like "john@doe.com".Split('@')[0]? My suggestion would be in the registration screen have a field for name that is bound to a field in your model (Nickname maybe?) and render that.